# Open sidemenu from a tabs page heade

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to create slide menu inside tad dashboard.Please check this code how to implement slide menus.

[`Sample code for tabs`](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9TBvqGZHkxyruScmR4Z?p=preview)

Please suggest me how to do. Slide menu in above code.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you want to create Slide Boxes and Tabs in Ionic Framework ?

Comment: yes i want slide box and tabs.

Comment: i am try to combining my code and you sent code in slide menu.at that time only i am not able to include you sent code into my code.How Can i solve these.